# $I$ is a free R-module if and only if $I = Ra$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

**Problem:** Let $I$ be a non-zero ideal of a commutative ring $R$ with identity. Prove that
$I$ is a free R-module if and only if $I = Ra$ for some $a \in R$ that is not a zero
divisor.

My idea is:
($\Rightarrow$) Let $I$ be generated by $\{a_1,...,a_n\} (n>1)$, then I have $a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n=0$, with $x_1=a_2,x_2=-a_1,...$($n$ is even); $x_1=a_2, x_2=-a_1-a_3, x_3=a_2, x_4=a_5, x_5=-a_4,...$ ($n$ is odd).
Thus, $a_1=\cdots=a_n=0$. Contradiction. Thus, $n=1$.

Is it right? Help me! Thanks!

Comment: It looks fine, though you only have to exhibit a linear dependence among a *subset* of your generators, so you can make your life easier by setting some of your $x_{i}$'s equal to $0$. (In particular, you then don't have to deal with cases based on the parity of $n$.) Also, your proof is not really by contradiction: your proof correctly shows that any finite set of elements of $I$ with cardinality $> 1$ is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks pretty good. You don't need your first sentence (your argument shows first of all that $I$ is  generated by one element without the assumption that it is finitely generated.)

After that, you can ignore the even/odd problem by just selecting a linearly independent subset with two elements.